# Put the values of $a , b$ and $c$ in the equation $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In the equation $a = (y - 1) , b = 0 , c = y$.

Put the values in the following equation

$$b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$$

Just tell me what answer you guys got.

The answer should be $0 \leq y \leq 1$

but my answer is $y \leq 0$ or $y \leq 1$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You get $y(1-y) \geq 0$. This is true if $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and false if $y >1$ or $y<0$ so the given answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have:

$$\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}\ge0\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$0^2-4\cdot\left(\text{y}-1\right)\cdot\text{y}\ge0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space0\le\text{y}\le1\tag2$$

__

Because:

$$0^2-4\cdot\left(\text{y}-1\right)\cdot\text{y}=4\cdot\text{y}\cdot\left(1-\text{y}\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{y}=0\space\wedge\space\text{y}=1\tag3$$